# Java get action command with a keyTyped event

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jtextfield, keyevent

I have a JTextField to which I set an action command with the method setActionCommand(String s).
It seems I can only get this action command when I use an actionPerformed event.

However I need to get some signature from my JTexteField with a keyTyped event, because I use several JTextFields, and I need to distinguish in which one the Enter key has been typed. Here is my snippet for the keyTyped event:

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent k) {
    String id = k.getComponent().getClass().getSimpleName();

    if (KeyEvent.VK_ENTER == k.getKeyChar() && "JTextField".equals( id )) {
        JTextField tempTxt = (JTextField) k.getComponent();
        // Here I would like to get my JTextField signature, such as k.getActionCommand() with actionPerformed() method
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However I need to get some signature from my JTexteField with a
>   keyTyped event, because I use several JTextFields, and I need to
>   distinguish in which one the Enter key has been typed. Here is my
>   snippet for the keyTyped event:

- use [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) added to [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) instead of [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)
- for `JTextComponents` to use [DocumentListener/DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)
- then easiest of ways could be

  1. [setName/getName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setName-java.lang.String-)
  2. [putClientProperty/getClientProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: Yes setName() works fine (see comment to nikis). thank you! ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `setName(String name)` on every `JTextField` you have and then you'll be able to distinguish them by calling `k.getComponent().getName()`

Comment: I don't know why I once used setName() and it did not do anything as expected. But now it works. I probably did something wrong previously. THanks for the answer! :)